# No Line Plotted

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

Minimum - not working - example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=2015-12-21 00:00:00,
xmax=2016-01-22 00:00:00,
hide y axis,
ymin= 0,
ymax = 1,
y = 1cm,
axis x line*=bottom,
date coordinates in=x,
date ZERO=2015-12-21 00:00:00,
width=6.5in,
xlabel style = {yshift=4mm,anchor=east},
x tick label style={
        rotate=45,yshift=-0.1cm,
        anchor=east,font=\large\bfseries}
]
\addplot [line width=6pt] table[col sep=comma] {
2015-12-21 06:31:00, 0.5
2016-01-13 08:41:00, 0.5
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i have removed the line-breaking tag.  that refers to lines of text, not drawn lines.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was still there (maybe reintroduced by edits occurring at the same time). I removed it.

Comment: @user39678 Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `header=false` to the configuration of the table input, as this is initially `true`, see p. 50 in the [latest `pgfplots` manual (v1.13)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). If you do not include this, the first row of the table will be used as column names.

So the following should work:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=2015-12-21 00:00:00,
xmax=2016-01-22 00:00:00,
hide y axis,
ymin= 0,
ymax = 1,
y = 1cm,
axis x line*=bottom,
date coordinates in=x,
date ZERO=2015-12-21 00:00:00,
width=6.5in,
xlabel style = {yshift=4mm,anchor=east},
x tick label style={
        rotate=45,yshift=-0.1cm,
        anchor=east,font=\large\bfseries}
]
\addplot [line width=6pt] table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
2015-12-21 06:31:00, 0.5
2016-01-13 08:41:00, 0.5
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]